# When import function from node module, why is module level code in the module also executed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, es6-modules

I have two .js files/modules in a node project. The module named "tester.js" imports an exported function from the "main.js" module.  The "main.js" module also contains the module level code that runs when node runs the module: `node main.js`.

The unexpected behavior I see is that when I use node to run the "tester.js" module, the module level code of the "main.js" module also executes. This code executes when the "tester.js" module imports a function from the "main.js" module.

Is this expected behavior?

The output when node runs the "tester.js" module:

```
$ npm run tester

> demo-import-from-main@1.0.0 tester
> node ./tester.js

running main.js
tester.js start.
tester.js. add numbers result:60
```

```
// main.js
console.log(`running main.js`);

export function add_numbers( v1, v2 )
{
  return v1 + v2;
}
```

```
// tester.js
import { add_numbers } from "./main.js";

console.log(`tester.js start.`);
const res = add_numbers(25, 35);
console.log(`tester.js. add numbers result:${res}`);
```

```
{
  "name": "demo-import-from-main",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "description": "demo that importing function from node module causes module level code to also run in the module.",
  "main": "./server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "main": "node ./main.js",
    "tester": "node ./tester.js"  
  }
}
```

Comment: If the code didn't execute, how would `const x = 1; export function fn(y) { return x + y }` work?

Comment: I am expecting the code to just be evaluated, not executed when a function is imported. I guess I understand that javascript does not work that way.

Comment: "*evaluated, not executed*" evaluation === execution. The two are synonyms. For a direct example, the `eval` function in JS **eval**uates code which executes it.

Comment: Yes, this is expected. When else would module-level code run?